# No output from search button

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have a search button on my web page and it should return the subject name from the DB which are similar to entered search word, but I didnt get any out put when I use the following code... please help me to do it...

this is my C# code

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=e-learningsystem; uid=root; password=123;port=3307;");
        connection.Open();
        string srh = editbox_search.Type;
        try
        {
          MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE Name= LIKE %'" + srh + "'%", connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            connection.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

asp.net code:

```
    <input name="editbox_search" class="editbox_search" id="editbox_search" 
              maxlength="80" type="text" 
              style="background-color: #99CCFF; margin-top: 0px; height: 15px;" runat="server" 
              enableviewstate="True" title="Search Courses:" clientidmode="Inherit" 
              dir="ltr" visible="True"/>            
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" 
              runat="server" Height="26px" Text="Go" Width="32px" />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True"
         Caption="<h3 style='background-color:teal;color:white;'>Search Results...</h3>" 
        BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" 
        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: have you checked that your database call is returning you anything in your dataset ds? have you checked it in debugger?

Answer (score 0):

There is Mistake in Your Query, Correct it as below.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE Name LIKE '%" + srh + "%'", connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a [parameterized command](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html) to avoid SQL injections.  Second, I think the value you are looking for is in the `Text` property of the input, not the `Type` property. Lastly, the single quotes go outside the matching characters, i.e., `'%searchvalue%'`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("connection string removed");
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE Name LIKE '%@input%'", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@input", editbox_search.Text);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        connection.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // log the exception
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("connection string removed");
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE Name LIKE '%'+@input+'%'", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", editbox_search.Text);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        da.Fill(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        connection.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // log the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: got a error in "text" part.. why is that???
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", editbox_search.Text);

Comment: Ok, got it! When you use `runat="server"` the id is changed. Go to view source of your page and try out to find the id of the textbox and edit `editbox_search.Text` with that.

Comment: doesnt contain a definition for text & no extension method text accepting a first argument type

Comment: Also remove `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` and try once, might be possible that it is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`? AND check the id in the **view source** not in properties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34302/discussion-between-aayushi-jain-and-jiya)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM subject WHERE Name LIKE %'" + srh + "'%
```